# How do I accept an invitation to a GitHub-hosted repository?

Tags: github

When I click the 'accept' link in an invitation that I've been emailed to a GIT repository, nothing happens. When I click the 'view invite', I get a 404. How do I accept the invite?

Comment: This is clearly not a Git issue. (It might be a GitHub issue, or perhaps something in the browser and/or email reader you're using.)

Answer (score 3):

I get a 404 if I click "view invitation" while not logged in to GitHub. Signing in via the 404 page displays the invitation.

Answer (score 1):

I got the repository administrator to email me the invite link:

(project page > settings > collaborators > Copy invite link).

When logged into Github in Chrome, paste the invite link into the browser as the Url, and the invite can then be accepted

Comment: Is there a generic link pattern. With the recent GitHub site updates, I see https://github.com/orgs/ORGANAME/teams/developers/members, but not a "copy invite link".